# Check if a given variable is selected in a select list/conditional based on this

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got the following:

```
$('#edit-profile-main-field-county-und option[value=' + code + ']').attr('selected', true);
```

The element is a select list with multiple options (and multiple options can be selected at once).

`code` is a variable that contains a value for the select list options.

Basically, I want to check if the option with `code` as the value is selected, and if it is, unselect it, rather than select it, like it is right now.

Every example I'm seeing checks ALL the selected values, and that's just not necessary in my case. This is for a select/unselect function on a map.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/

Comment: This is not what I want. I do not want all selected items. I want to check if one item is selected. I could use this and check the list for the value I suppose, but I was hoping for something that would just check directly, without having to grab all the other options.

Comment: Select your one specific option, and _combine_ that with `:selected` – if that one option is selected, you will get that one option element back, and if not, you will get an empty jQuery object …

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved the problem:

```
if($('#edit-profile-main-field-county-und option[value=' + code + ']').attr('selected') == 0) {
      $('#edit-profile-main-field-county-und option[value=' + code + ']').attr('selected', true);
      }
      else if($('#edit-profile-main-field-county-und option[value=' + code + ']').attr('selected') == 1) {
            $('#edit-profile-main-field-county-und option[value=' + code + ']').attr('selected', false);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using jquery > 1.6 you can use [`prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) method like this

```
var option = $('#edit-profile-main-field-county-und option[value=' + code + ']');
option.prop('selected', !option.prop('selected'));
```

Comment: Does the .attr() method not work in versions past 1.6?